# Auto -generate tables in sql server from Mvc 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Can I auto- generate tables in sql server just writing the model in VS like in case of first time registration in Mvc 4.0 internet application ?

Comment: you want to create all the tables or just the basic tables?

Comment: The thing you need to search is Code First/POCO technology

Comment: Basic tables like for roles and Users are already generated by VS automatically. I want to create new tables for contact info and personal details of the user.

Comment: answered for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These Links will help you get Started:

[Mvc Code First For Begginers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSgAA8y5ViU) on YouTube

[Building an HTML5 End-to-End Web Application with ASP.NET MVC 4, EF Code First and jQuery](http://www.interfacett.com/training/web-development-net-development-visual-studio/dev500-building-html5-end-end-web-application-aspnet-mvc-4-ef-code-first-and-jquery) video on interfacett.com

[Code First with Entity Framework 5 using MVC4 and MVC Scaffold](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/468777/Code-First-with-Entity-Framework-using-MVC-and) article on CodeProject

Answer (score 1):

Try this you can find it with full description on Musicstore Tutorial for MVC (Creating DB Code First)

```
public class ClassEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Class1> Class1 { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Class2> Class2 { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Class3> Class3 { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>().ToTable("Class1");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Class2>().ToTable("Class2");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Class3>().ToTable("Class3");

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is best example for your requirement
[**Building an MVC 3 App with Code First and Entity Framework 4.1**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/gg685467.aspx)